Problem dynamically importing components at runtime NextJS
I am trying to dynamically import components at runtime based on configuration provided in data.
I have created a DynamicComponant that  accepts a component identifier and its associated props object, which then looks up the component path and attempts to dynamically load it and pass it its props.
type Props = {
    id: string,
    dynamicProps: Record<string, any>
}

const DynamicComponent = (props: Props) => {

   const {id, dynamicProps} = props;

   const [Component, setComponent] = useState<ReactNode | null>(null);

   const loadComponent = async (componentName: string) => {
     const config = componentConfig.find((c) => c.name === componentName);
     if (config) {
        const Component = dynamic(() => import(config.importPath));
        setComponent(<Component {...dynamicProps} />);
     } else {
        setComponent(null);
     }
   };

   useEffect(() => {
     loadComponent(id);
   },[id]);

   return (
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        {Component}
      </Suspense>
   ) 
};

With this I get the Error: Cannot find module '[component path]'
However, If I substitute config.importPath with a hardcoded path that matches the one being passed to it, it works and renders the component as expected.
What am I doing wrong?
